# How to make a for loop that prints horizontally

Tags: javascript

I want a loop that print 5 random numbers that will print vertically

so far I have...

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
console.log(x)
}
```

Then when I run it I got 5 random numbers and I just don't know how to print it horizontally

Comment: So push them to an array and write out the array

Comment: How would i be able to do that i am new

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: In the loop you do `array.push(x)`; After the loop you do `console.log(array);`

Comment: so instide the loop before the console.log i would put array.push(x); ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your desired output format, but you can do something like this:

```js
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  arr.push(x)
  console.log(x)
}
console.log(...arr)
```

If you want to do it with commas you dan do it with e.g. .map().

```js
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  arr.push(x);
  console.log(x);
}
const len = arr.length;
const commaArray = arr.map((x, i) => i < len - 1 ? x + ',' : x);
console.log(...commaArray);
```

Comment: so i need to seperate it with a comma and if i do it with commas then when i run it with commas it puts a comma in front of the first number i.e. , 10, 4, 3, 9...

Comment: I added another function if you want a comma output, maybe you can do it even with the spread operator but not sure about it

Answer (score 0):

You could just add them all onto a big string and print that at the end!

```js
output = ''
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    output = output + ' ' + x;
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
var values=[];
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
   values.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
}
console.log(values);    //if you want to print an array
console.log(values.join()); //if you want to print as string with coma sepration
console.log(values.join(" ")); //if you want to print as string with empty spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

By printing horizontally I'm assuming you mean in the same line. In that case, you do what was mentioned above, or you can create a string with all the numbers

```
let string = "";
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
   let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
   string = `${string} ${x.toString()}`;
}
console.log(string);
```